# Modifying dates directly from firebase console produces errors in my app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am rendering readable dates in my app. For dates which are stored via cloud functions/client I am not having any problems. But, if I do these steps, all start going bad:

1. Store date via cloud function in firestore
2. Modify the date directly in the firebase console [!!!]
3. Get the modified date from a cloud function (calling it, so the GCF returns a serialized date)

Then, I get this date:

```
Object {
  "_nanoseconds": 0,
  "_seconds": 1612190050,
}
```

So, if I run this code:

```
// Convert the date to a Firestore Timestamp if necessary
if (date._seconds && date._nanoseconds) {
  const { _seconds, _nanoseconds } = date;
  date = new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(_seconds, _nanoseconds);
}


console.log(getReadableTimeSince(date.toDate());
```

The code will work for those dates returned from the GCF which weren't directly modified in the Firebase console. But, it will throw an exception for the directly touched:

> date.toDate is not a function. (In 'date.toDate()', 'date.toDate' is
> undefined)

Instead, if I do

```
 console.log(getReadableTimeSince(date.toDate?.() || date);
```

all works perfectly, but why?

Why `new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(_seconds, _nanoseconds)` doesn't work with the serialized dates that were previously modified directly in the Firebase console?

Note:

the GCF returns always dates following this format

```
 {_seconds: 1022322, _nanoseconds: 129921}
```

For dates which hasn't be modified, I can do new `firebase.firestore.Timestamp(_seconds, _nanoseconds)` and be able to access `.toDate()` method

Comment: Make sure that when you edit properties in Firebase console, you select the correct type, whether that is a Date object or something else.

Comment: the issue was that _nanoseconds was 0, so I have to make a type validation to run the crucial code

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a firestore is, but this code

```
   if (date._seconds && date._nanoseconds)
```

evaluates to false if either field is zero, and you set nanoseconds to zero.

```
Object {
  "_nanoseconds": 0,
  "_seconds": 1612190050,
}
```

The clause that insists nanoseconds be non-zero looks flawed to me; zero nanos is perfectly legal (though infrequent, perhaps).